# How to have a smooth horizontal webview scrolling in android

Tags: android, webview, horizontal-scrolling

I am inflating a web view in to gallery view in a layout and loading content to the web view, here the problem is the horizontal scrolling is not smooth and I want to implement like the pages should be followed like when I scroll the next page should also follow as in gallery but this is not happening in my case.

How to make it smooth and have a gallery feel, please help me I have not implemented any onTouch or onFling events. help me

Comment: Is it necessary to use a WebView as a gallery item? I think the overhead is huge so your described performance impact seems to be the logic result...

Comment: yes, i have to use webview inside a gallery view that is the requirement

Comment: I don't think that you then can improve the performance. As I don't know why you need webviews (what are you displaying?), I can't provide more help.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an ArrayList (let's call it mViews) with all the views to be shown when you initializes the adapter. Then in your getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View aboutView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    return mViews.get(position);
}
```

This will of course have an impact when you first load the view. But the Gallery should run more smooth.

Comment: Or even better - take a look at the ViewPager class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html. The Gallery is best for images. If you present other data, it is better to use the ViewPageris better for your purpose than the Gallery.